# Adding Attributes to Visio UML Interface Like a Class

Tags: interface, attributes, visio, uml

Is it possible to add attributes to a Visio (in my case 2007) UML diagram Interface object?  It shows operations in its properties dialog, but alas no Attributes section.  I am really hoping someone has thought of a way around this (without looking at third-party apps).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to achieve the same visual Effect: An interface is represented like a class with a stereotype `<<interface>>`. So you can go to UML/Stereotypes/New and enter "interface" as Stereotype name, then select Class as base. Now you can Create a new Class, edit it and select the new interface stereotype. After doing so you have a visual representation of an interface which can hold attributes.

Maybe this suites your needs. Still the internal representation of these models is not UML 2 compliant (but Visio has other flaws regarding that either way).

Comment: That worked (at least giving it the visual representation I was looking for).  Thanks!

Comment: Curiously enough though... I just got to wondering, Visio automatically updates those classes that implement an interface to display the methods... can this approach be setup to also do that?